# How to link the slider value to the audio position in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, audio, slider

I am trying to create a gas pedal and RPM sort of application. The UI consists of a slider which acts as the gas pedal and the slider value which acts as the RPM value. I have two audio which is EXHAUST_ACCEL and EXHAUST_DECEL. Currently, I have coded where it detects when the slider is increasing and plays EXHAUST_ACCEL. When the slider is decreasing it, it plays EXHAUST_DECEL.

The audio is broken up to 9000 parts as the slider has a range of 9000.

The problem is when I move the slider, it should play the audio part of the designated slider position. For example when the slider is at 4500 it should play the audio part at 4500 repeatedly over and over again until I move on to the next part. When I slide the slider, it should smoothly start playing the following audio parts. Instead, whenever I move the slider, it plays the audio track from the beginning.

The two main stuff that I want it to work is

1. When the slider is at a stagnant position, it should play the audio part of that position over and over again until the slider is moved
2. The audio part being played should be determined by the audio position.

My aim is to try and mimic how the gas pedal, RPM and exhaust sound works and links up together in real life

The audio files are in this Google drive link:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qTt808TNdIeNPXVOS2lBvhdlJvTVB3dC?usp=sharing

The codes are below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pygame

# Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Set up the window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Slider UI")
window.geometry("400x200")

# Load the audio files
accel_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("EXHAUST_ACCEL.wav")
decel_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("EXHAUST_DECEL.wav")

# Calculate the number of audio parts
total_parts = 9000

# Calculate the duration of each audio part
part_duration = accel_sound.get_length() / total_parts

# Initialize the slider value and audio time
slider_value = tk.StringVar()
audio_time = 0

# Create a label to display the slider value
value_label = ttk.Label(window, textvariable=slider_value)
value_label.pack()

# Create the slider
slider = ttk.Scale(window, from_=0, to=total_parts, orient="horizontal", length=300)
slider.pack()

# Function to handle slider movements
def slider_moved(event):
    global audio_time
    
    # Get the slider value
    slider_value = int(slider.get())
    
    # Calculate the new audio time based on the slider value
    new_audio_time = (slider_value / total_parts) * accel_sound.get_length()
    
    # Play the appropriate audio file and update the audio time
    if new_audio_time > audio_time:
        print("This is increasing")
        if pygame.mixer.Channel(0).get_sound() != accel_sound:
            pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(accel_sound, fade_ms=200)
    elif new_audio_time < audio_time:
        print("This is decreasing")
        if pygame.mixer.Channel(0).get_sound() != decel_sound:
            pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(decel_sound, fade_ms=200)
    audio_time = new_audio_time
    
    # Update the slider position
    update_slider_position()

# Function to update the slider position based on the audio time
def update_slider_position():
    slider.set((audio_time / accel_sound.get_length()) * total_parts)
    slider_value.set(f"Slider Value: {slider.get()}")

# Bind the slider movement to the slider_moved function
slider.bind("<B1-Motion>", slider_moved)

# Start the main loop
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of your code always starts playing the sound from the beginning when you change the slider position. The root of the issue is that the pygame.mixer.Sound.play() method doesn't have an option to start playback from a specific position.

However, the pygame.mixer.music module, which is intended for stream playback (perfect for long audio files), does have the pygame.mixer.music.play(start) method which accepts a start parameter indicating the number of seconds from the beginning of the music that playback should start from.

You could refactor your code to use pygame.mixer.music instead of pygame.mixer.Sound and pygame.mixer.Channel, and then set the start parameter to new_audio_time when calling pygame.mixer.music.play(). This would allow you to start the audio from the correct position corresponding to the slider value.

Also, to repeatedly play the same section of audio when the slider is not moving, you might need to set a timer that restarts playback from new_audio_time every part_duration seconds. Be sure to cancel the timer when the slider starts moving again.